# ECDHE Cipher not being displayed

Tags: ssl, apache-2.4, openssl

I am trying to fully support forward secrecy on my FreeBSD Apache 2.4.16 server. I am using the correct cipher suite as the same cipher order works correctly on a different FreeBSD server. However, when I attempt to SSL test the server, the ECDHE cipher suites do not appear, even though running `openssl ciphers` shows that they exist.

What could be the cause for this?

The configured ciphers are these:

> SSLCipherSuite ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256-GCM-SHA384:AES128-SHA256:AES256-SHA256:AES128-SHA:AES256-SHA:DES-CBC3-SHA:!DSS

Comment: What's your ciphers config string?

Comment: @StackzOfZtuff updated original post with cipher suite

Comment: What kind of certificate did you install? RSA or ECDSA?

Comment: @StackzOfZtuff RSA. Would that be the cause?

Comment: @StackzOfZtuff I just confirmed that it is an issue with Apache or Openssl, and not virtualhost specific. I installed a different certificate on a different subdomain, and the issue persists.

Comment: This wouldn't happen to be a CPanel server would it ?

Comment: Could you post the output of the https://testssl.sh/ script here?

Answer (score 1):

The root of the issue seems to occur with the mod_security2 2.9.0 module that I was using. It doesn't like ECDHE so it doesn't allow it.